# Text change in TextBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have some 32 TextBoxes and 1 "Save" button. What I want is to save the text for only those TextBoxes which have their Texts changed. How can I achieve that? How do I know the text of which TextBoxes have changed?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would do it server-side. Assuming you have no data binding involved, you could do something like the following in your ASPX.CS code-behind:

```
...

private string InitialValue1 
{ 
    get { return ViewState[@"IV1"] as string; } 
    set { ViewState[@"IV1"] = value; }
}
// Repeat for all 32 text boxes.

protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if(!IsPostBack )
    {
        TextBox1.Text = InitialValue1 = loadText1FromDatabase();
        // Repeat for all 32 text boxes.
    }
}

protected void MySaveButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if ( TextBox1.Text!=InitialValue1 ) saveText1ToDatabase( TextBox1.Text );
    // Repeat for all 32 text boxes.
}

...
```

Of course, in a real-world-scenario, I would do some looping/array handling instead of writing 32 same functions/properties.

Comment: just my preference - I wouldn't store in ViewState. If viewstate validation is off, values can be changed intentionally and it also increases the size of the already bloated viewstate. I do agree 100% though - this should be server side.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a jQuery function on load to make a fake old data input.
Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$(":text").each(
var newid=$(this).attr("id") + "_old";
var oldvalue=$(this).val();
var formy=$("form");
formy.appendChild("<input type='hidden' name='" + newid +"' value='" + oldvalue +"'>);
})
```

This way, if you change the number, the function automatically writes the correct number for you.
Then on the server side you can compare the values with something like below :

```
var inputs = Request.Form.Keys.Where(rs=>rs.Contains("_old"));
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
  //check the _old vs the input without the old and do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect this on the client side for keypress, or compare the values on post and send over a list of items that changed.
However if you want to do this on the server side, you will *have to* load up your server data and manually compare it against every textbox.

Comment: that sounds to be a huge amount of work.. :( is it worth the pain? how can that be done by onkeypress event?? if onkeypress is true even then we have to check for each of the 32 textboxes???

Comment: Personally I would just do this on the server side - its more reliable as well.  In the above case you could do this several ways though, I would load up a javascript array of textbox ids and values, and upon post figure out which ones don't match the array and then send in the ids in a hidden field that changed. But.. I would do this on the server. Client side code can always be bypassed/ modified. PLEASE don't follow some of the recommendations above with cookies, etc. As much as everyones input is appreciated - cookies and session make this a very unclean solution. Simply load the data

Comment: on the server side and compare to the posted values. If you use an automapper to map values on the page into an object and compare the object - its even cleaner to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Use session variables to store the data for every postback and compare the values. If the value of a certain textbox changes then save that otherwise dont save.

Comment: Session variables are not sequence friendly. You then rely on a session, a session can timeout in between requests, you assume the user is accessing the pages in a certain order, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do using HiddenFields. on page load you can set HiddenFields with original TextBox values. 
on save button you can compare HiddenFields value with TextBox value, If HiddenField value does not 
match with TextBox value then you can save that TextBox value in DB otherwise not.

Comment: If you are not using .net 3.5 or above this is the best way to do it. Otherwise I recomend to look at the IPostBackDataHandler as @V4Vendetta mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookie variables to store the data for every postback and compare the values.

Comment: I wouldn't - you are asking for trouble. What if cookies are cleared? What if cookie expires? What if the values stay around from a prior session because the page is cached and doesnt match upon post? What if multiple instance of the same page are open?

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using, In case of 3.5 and above i would request you to check on this [IPostBackDataHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342354.aspx). This should help you in achieving what you want.

In previous versions i think you will have to do it only by comparing it with the original text or the least you could use the **MERGE** keyword
(you will have to modify your db queries) while you are pushing your records into the database.